# Persist Chrome Dev Tools Preferences in Incognito

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

Is it possible for chrome dev tools to remember preferences when loading a new incognito session?

I prefer to have dev tools docked on the right - and it's annoying to constantly set this every time a new incognito instance is started.

A similar question was filed as an issue on the chromium project here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's possible only with Chrome Canary:

> DevTools will now persist your appearance preferences (docking
>   position, size, pane layout, etc) and devtools settings (disable
>   cache, etc) into the incognito window.

[About the feature](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/24/better-incognito-devtools?hl=en)

[Download Chrome Canary here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html)